Simplifying trig expression answer is $1$
Simplify
$\cos^2(v) + \sin^2(-v)$
Attempt:
$\cos^2(v) + \sin^2(-v) = 1$
$\cos^2v + \sin v = 1$
$\sqrt{\cos^2v} + \sin v = 1$
$\cos v + \sin v = 1$
The answer in the book is $1$ after the simplification.
I am using this table:

AI:


Your attempt gives 1, just as you say the book does, so what's the issue?

@Henriksupportsthecommunity, since I am still new to this, and currently struggling, I check against the internet to verify with others that know for sure, if my steps are correct here or not. I am studying this type of math from home. Remotely. Meaning, it takes days for a teacher to answer your questions. So, after a while, I post here.

Then say in the post that you are looking for verification of your solution.

Note that $\sin^2(-x)$ is an even function, in fact since $\sin x$ is odd, you have:
$$\sin^2(-x)=\sin(-x)\cdot\sin(-x)=(-\sin x)\cdot(-\sin x)=\sin^2(x) $$
Hence the answer is $1$.

Hi, the sin of negative one times itself, does become positive, the way I expected. Or, I missed something, I see in your answer. I am still new to this.

So, I should never have taken the Square Root of the $cos^2v$ there, hmm!

@AlixBlaine Sorry, I don't understand your question

In my third step under my attempt, I shouldn't have taken the square root of $cos^2v$ then, but rather, applied your method and the answer would be: $cos^2v + sin^2v = 1$

@AlixBlaine Why in the second step $\sin^2(-v)$ become $\sin v$?

Because of the multiplication with one self! $sin v \times sin v$ but in reversed, i.e., negative times negative thus, positive sin v.

You can't consider the square root of $\cos^2 x$ while leaving the other terms.

Yes, you are correct. Sorry!

@AlixBlaine No need to be sorry

@SineoftheTime, thanks a lot. Salam alaykum!!!

Note that $\sin^2 (-x)$ means $\sin(-x)$ has been raised to the second power i.e.
$\sin^2 (-x)$ = $\ [sin(-x)]^2$ = $\ [-sin(x)]^2$ = $\sin^2 (x)$
Hence, $\ cos^2(x) + sin^2 (-x)$ => $\ cos^2(x) + sin^2 (x)$
Which gives 1 , the desired result.

How is this different from my answer?

Couldn't see your answer (glitch prolly). Sorry.

@KrishangRana, thanks for your attempt. +1 from me.
